# Zend File form element textarea is misplaced

Tags: php, file-upload, zend-form-element

When I create a Zend File Form Element and place it onto my view, the components are strangly placed. See picture, https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJjB5.png . As you can see on the picture, the input field has jumped down or the label went up. I can't understand why this is, please advice!

Below are my code generating this element.

```
private function _getFileElement($category = 0) {
    if ($category == 1) {
        $fileElement = $this->createElement('file', 'file_email');
    } else if ($category == 2) {
        $fileElement = $this->createElement('file', 'file_letter');
    } else {
        $fileElement = $this->createElement('file', 'file');
    }

    $fileElement->setLabel('Egen mall')
    ->setAttrib('style', 'width:300px;')
    ->setDestination('/tmp/');
    $fileElement->addValidator('Count', false, 1);

    return $fileElement;
}
```

This is added later on my view.

Best regards,

Gabriel Paulsson

Comment: I believe zend outputs the form properly in dd and dt tags.  I think browsers interpret the file tag and make it look like that.  I could be wrong though.  You probably should check out form decorators.

Comment: Try in your CSS: label {float: left; width: your-width-in-px;}

Comment: @DirkMcQuickly wouldnt that affect all labels in the form? Don't think that would be preferable.

Comment: @Gabriel You're right. But maybe it generates the desired output. There's no harm in trying, and otherwise: CTRL-Z ;-)

Comment: @tubaguy50035, indeed it was the decorators that caused this. Do you know how to modify so I can get those dtdd into a div and set a style to it?

Comment: Nevermind, solved it. As @tubaguy50035 pointed me towards the right direction, post your comment as answer and I will accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe zend outputs the form properly in dd and dt tags. I think browsers interpret the file tag and make it look like that. I could be wrong though. You probably should check out form decorators.